# .NET HttpClient send arbitrary Authorization header

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, header, authorization

Using HttpClient is it possible to construct Authorization headers of arbitrary syntax ?

If I use the syntax HttpClient expects :

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth2", <token>);
```

it will pass this header :

```
Authorization: OAuth2 <token-value>
```

However, I'm sending my requests to a remote REST API that requires the authorization header to be in this format :

```
Authorization: token <token-value>
```

How to send the required format ?

Comment: Where is the difference? Just use "token" instead of OAuth2?