# Using HttpClient, send an Authorization token with no schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

**Note:** This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155552/net-httpclient-send-arbitrary-authorization-header), but its suggested answer doesn't apply here.

I am trying to access [this API](https://www.lendingclub.com/developers/authentication.action), which is looking for a header that looks like this:

```
Authorization: {token}
```

Note the absence of any authentication scheme.

I have tried doing:

```
myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("", authToken);
```

Which resulted in an ArgumentException saying that I can't pass an empty string.

I have also tried both:

```
myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(authToken);
```

and

```
myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authToken);
```

Both of which result in a FormatException.

There seems to be something forcing me to conform to a standard format for my authorization header, but the service I am trying to access doesn't use that standard format.

Comment: try adding accepted type
myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try:

```
request.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", token));
```

as mentioned in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875106(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Spent 2 hours to make the `HttpRequest` work... I needed to use this without the schema.

Nice... it's working now!

Comment: This C# HttpClient class sucks...

Answer (score 7):

As seems to happen so often, right after I ask the question I find the answer.

The standard format that HttpClinet is holding me to is the Http protocol itself, which requires an authentication scheme, however there is a work-around.

instead of:

```
myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authToken);
```

You can use:

```
myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authToken);
```

Which ignores the Http standard and just lets you add the header however you need.

Comment: Hehehe... saved my life after 2 hours of trial and error to make the `HttpRequest` work...